# A question on factorial rings

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory, prime-factorization

Is 31 irreducible in the ring $\mathbb{Z}\left[\sqrt{5}\right]=\left\{a+b\sqrt{5}:a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}$ 
 ?

And is it prime in $\mathbb{Z}\left[\sqrt{5}\right]$?

Comment: Have you tried to factor it as $(a+b\sqrt{5})(a-b\sqrt{5})$?

Comment: Hint: $31=36-5$.

Comment: @anon          yes I did it, took its norm and solved the system. I found it irreducible but I'm not sure because I don't have much background in number theory...

Comment: But vadim just gave you a factorisation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that for $x$ to be *irreducible* means that for any factorization of $x$, at least one of the factors is a unit (ie. has a multiplicative inverse).  As with the hints given by anon and vadim, you have $(6+\sqrt{5})(6-\sqrt{5})=31$.  Now, is either of these factors a unit?

Suppose $(a+b\sqrt{5})$ is a unit.  Then, for some $(c+d\sqrt{5})$, we have:
 $$(a+b\sqrt{5})(c+d\sqrt{5})=1 \\
\text{(multiply both sides by complex conjugate)} \implies (a^2-5b^2)(c^2-5d^2)=1
$$
Since all of our variables are integers, this forces $a^2-5b^2=\pm 1$.  You can easily check that neither $(6+\sqrt{5})$ or $(6-\sqrt{5})$ satisfy this condition -- hence neither are units.  Thus, we have a nontrivial factorization of $31$, so it is *not* irreducible.

Now recall that in any integral domain, $x$ is a prime element $\implies$ $x$ is an irreducible element.  Hence by contrapositive, $x$ is not an irreducible element $\implies$ $x$ is not a prime element.  Since $31$ is not irreducible, it is not prime.

Comment: thanks! I had it done but then I got confused. now its clear again